# Regular Expression excluding of expression

Tags: php, regex

I am using regular expression to get URL in 
the format  **www.example.com/abc/def/xyz** 
so i have used regular expressinon  " abc/def/.*? " 
but this also fetches me url in the format 
**www.example.com/abc/def/xyz/Some_url**

How do I get the URL which doesnot contain any sublevels after 
level of xyz ?

Comment: As Colin said -- you've asked 6 questions that gathered 10 answers so far. Time for you to do some acceptance...

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your URL will be followed by a space and not some other whitespace character (e.g. newline) or a punctuation mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
abc/def/[^/]*$
```

The `$` makes sure there are no `/` characters until the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude slash in the remaining characters by using a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
"#abc/def/[^/]*? #"
```